# Remove "product" slug from Woocommerce Link

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, slug

I have one issue that cant resolve myself, so need your help. I have Woocommerce store where i sell my personal things. Somehow i removed "product-category" slug from URL, and now i want to do the same for product too.

For example for category i have:

```
example.net/digital-products/sound-kits/808-kits/
```

and want to do the same for product, and remove "product" slug from [URL](http://example.net/digital-products/product/808-touchdown-v1/)

Currently is like this:

```
http://example.net/digital-products/product/808-touchdown-v1/
```

and want to be like this:

```
 http://example.net/digital-products/sound-kits/808-kits/808-touchdown-v1
```

Is possible this?

Comment: I think you just need to change the permalink structure to included the product category before the product name: http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-include-category-and-subcategory-in-wordpress-urls/

Comment: That is for Wordpress posts and pages. Im asking for Woocommerce slugs.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the *Permalink Settings* page, and under *Product Permalinks* (at the bottom of the page), enter `/sound-kits/` in the *Custom base* field. Then just save your changes.

Comment: That is OK, but there are more then one category then sound-kits. Is have another product category, then your asnwer will be wrong.

Comment: I see. "*Somehow i removed "product-category" slug from URL*" — how did you do that? Just curious, and perhaps we could apply the same to the product slug.

Comment: I might have a solution for you. But may I know your permalink structure? (for standard Posts, in the "Common Settings" section of the "Permalink Settings" page)